# deflate on custom stream in node.js

Tags: node.js, compression, node.js-stream

I have a simple script:

```
const {Readable} = require('stream')
const zlib = require('zlib');
const deflate = zlib.createDeflate();
var read = new Readable();
read._read = function () {};
read.pipe(deflate).pipe(process.stdout);
var i = 0;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if(i == 10) {
        read.push(null)
        clearInterval(interval)
    } else {
        read.push(JSON.stringify(i++));
    }
}, 1000);
```

it prints only a single value like below:

```
x�
```

I was expecting a series of 9 value which works fine if I just remove `deflate` from pipe

```
read.pipe(process.stdout);
```

I got 9 value printed like below:

```
0123456789
```

So, why adding `deflate` doesn't print 9 values?

Comment: That is the fun about  `compression` %)P.

Comment: @AJAX the sample code is just to display the problem in simple way, but the actual use-case contains much larger value which requires compression. But the fundamental problem remains same :)

Comment: No. The fun about `compression` is, that is `compresses`. If it is more than the `input` `value` it is critical.